# A successor of amarok?

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, audio-player

I liked Amarok as a music player, where it's more of a library manager that also plays things rather than a "virtual physical player gadget" in the style of WinAmp. Alas, Amarok seems to be dead as a project.

What players/media library managers in the same vein are under active development/maintenance which I might use as a replacement for Amarok?

The player needs to support Linux and be both libre and gratis. Being lightweight is a plus.

Comment: You can check out a range of options - not necessarily Amarok-like - on [Wikipedia's comparison of FOSS audio players](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_software_for_audio#Players).

Answer (score 1):

As said over on unix.se, clementine.

Even if they haven't done a formal release, is somewhat actively maintained, and is shipped in a current state by many distros.

(It's a bit redundant to ask her after you've gotten that recommendation over at unix.se and not even mention it in your question, don't you think?)

Comment: I was actually thinking you wouldn't make the recommendation because of the lack of official release. Anyway, +1.